# Getting a subarray of hashes

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting, hash

I have an array of hashes like this, which is sorted by the value for `:a`:

```
[{:a=>0, :b=>10}, {:a=>0, :b=>35}, {:a=>1, :b=>20}, {:a=>2, :b=>0}]
```

How can I get a subset of this array that has the hashes with the minimum value for `:a`?
Here, the minimum value for `:a` is `0`, so I need:

```
[{:a=>0, :b=>10}, {:a=>0, :b=>35}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it seems that the accepted answer makes the assumption that the `:a` value of the first element in the array is the minimum. So if the array were modified where `:a => 1` in the first element, then the result is incorrect. Here's the example:

```
# original
z = [{:a=>0, :b=>10}, {:a=>0, :b=>35}, {:a=>1, :b=>20}, {:a=>2, :b=>0}]
puts z.select{|y| y[:a] == z.first[:a]}.inspect
# => [{:a=>0, :b=>10}, {:a=>0, :b=>35}] the result is the expected one

# modified :a of first element
z = [{:a=>1, :b=>10}, {:a=>0, :b=>35}, {:a=>1, :b=>20}, {:a=>2, :b=>0}]
puts z.select{|y| y[:a] == z.first[:a]}.inspect
# => [{:a=>1, :b=>10}, {:a=>1, :b=>20}] here result does not have min :a
```

Now, not making that assumption I'm taking the extra step of finding the minimum value of `:a`

```
z = [{:a=>0, :b=>10}, {:a=>0, :b=>35}, {:a=>1, :b=>20}, {:a=>2, :b=>0}]
# find the min :a
m = z.map { |y| y[:a] }.min
puts z.select{|y| y[:a] == m}.inspect
# => [{:a=>0, :b=>10}, {:a=>0, :b=>35}]

# modified :a of first element
z = [{:a=>1, :b=>10}, {:a=>0, :b=>35}, {:a=>1, :b=>20}, {:a=>2, :b=>0}]
m = z.map { |y| y[:a] }.min
puts z.select{|y| y[:a] == m}.inspect
# => [{:a=>0, :b=>35}]
```

Comment: Hi Marc,
I didn't even notice before the trouble I would run into, so many, many thanks !

Comment: Actually the question itself mentions that "Ihave an array of hashes like this, which is sorted by the value for :a", which is where I got the assumption from :)

Answer (score 3):

```
z = [{:a=>0, :b=>10}, {:a=>0, :b=>35}, {:a=>1, :b=>20}, {:a=>2, :b=>0}]
z.select{|y| y[:a] == z.first[:a]}
```